# How to get epoch time in Redshift?

Tags: sql, database, amazon-redshift

In my schema I have a created_on field. I want to assign EPOCH time value to it automatically on insert. How to achieve that?

Answer (score 4):

```
select date_part(epoch,sysdate)::int
```

If I’ve made a bad assumption please comment and I’ll refocus my answer.

Answer (score 1):

On PostgreSQL (from with redshift was forked) you would do it like this:

```
ALTER TABLE sometable ALTER COLUMN created_on SET DEFAULT EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM now())
```

Maybe it works in redshift as well.

Comment: Apparently this is giving an error: ALTER COLUMN SET/DROP DEFAULT is not supported;

My table is blank so I don't mind creating one from scratch. However, the column type for EXTRACT is date_part. Is it possible to cast it as Integer? I am using epoch time as a version number.

Comment: I think that date_part is just a default name for result of EXTRACT() function. Return type in redshift should be integer, according to documentation: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_EXTRACT_function.html
It is different from PostgreSQL, where you get real as return type. So you shouldn't need to cast it.

Answer (score 1):

RedShift does not have now() but has getdate() instead, so this would be the expression to get the epoch:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM GETDATE());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM now());
```